# Best practice calling 1 or 2 async functions

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have blog posts stored in a remote database. Users can rate and/or comment on each post.  So I need to fire off 1 or 2 different network requests. But I must wait until they (or it) completes.

What is the best practice for the following scenario:

```
func updateRatingAndComment (){
        if commentTextView.text != "" {
            updateComment()
        }
        if ratingView.rating != 0.0 {
            updateRating()
        }
    }
```

`updateComment()` and `updateRating()` are Alamofire calls.

I've tried using dispatch groups but failed.  I'm thinking about using a callback but that doesn't seem to make sense (to me) either.

Comment: Is a combined request not an option? And a callback makes perfect sense.

Comment: Update your question with the code you tried and clearly explain what issues you had.

Comment: rmaddy.  The approach taken by Alexander (who just answered) was exactly what I tried  I can't get Dispatch Groups to work for the reason I stated below.

Comment: Right. But if you had posted your attempted code in your question, people could have pointed out your mistake.

Comment: @rmaddy.  As it turns out you are right.  I had not deployed Group Dispatch properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let group = DispatchGroup() // Controller property

 .....
        if commentTextView.text != "" {
            group.enter()
            updateComment() // self?.group.leave() inside callback
        }
        if ratingView.rating != 0.0 {
            group.enter()
            updateRating() // self?.group.leave() inside callback
        }

        group.notify(queue: .main) { [weak self] in
            // Do something
        }
....
```

Comment: Alexander.  Let's say there is both a comment and a rating.  You enter the comment set group.enter.  if the comment finishes before the rating does, it will fire group.leave and group.notify will fire before rating has finished.

Comment: But there were 2 enters. I currently use such approach in my app for 3 request and it works fine!

Comment: group.notify will fire when enters - leaves == 0

Comment: OK.  it's clear to me now that I must have been calling leave outside of the call back.  Thank You!